# iTextSharp PDF header with HTML string C#

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to generate PDF reports using iTextSharp with customer information, header and footer etc. All these reports are already generated using EVO APIs. As part of a migration process, we are planning to generate these reports using iTextSharp APIs.

I need to know if there is any possibility to provide a ready to render HTML string to iTextSharp PDF header (Existing EVO design accepts HTML string and build PDF), instead of using PageEvents to design with PDFPTable and PDFPCell (as the number of reports are huge and to avoid rework)

Comment: If an answer sufficiently answers a question you posted here, you should consider accepting it (clicking on the tick on the upper left of the answer). If it does not, you should add a comment in which you describe in which way it fails to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to know if there is any possibility to provide a ready to render HTML string to iTextSharp PDF header (Existing EVO design accepts HTML string and build PDF), instead of using PageEvents to design with PDFPTable and PDFPCell

You will have to use *page events* to draw header or footers but there is no need to use `PdfPTable` explicitly there. You actually can render html during a page event, e.g. like this:

```
[Test]
public void CreatePdfWithHtmlHeader()
{
    string htmlHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table style=\"width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;\"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table></body></html>";

    using (FileStream output = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test-results\content\html-header.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        writer.PageEvent = new HtmlPageEventHelper(htmlHeader);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("1"));
        document.NewPage();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("2"));
    }
}
```

making use the following two small helper classes.

`HtmlPageEventHelper` is a page event listener drawing a given html sniplet into the page header. Obviously it can alternatively or additionally write into the page footer, simply use appropriate column coordinates

```
public class HtmlPageEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public HtmlPageEventHelper(string html)
    {
        this.html = html;
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(html));
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-20), 10, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        ct.Go();
    }

    string html = null;
}
```

For more complex HTML sniplets you may want to replace the `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml` call by a customized parser call as presented in @Skary's answer.

`ColumnTextElementHandler` is an `IElementHandler` implementation that adds content (generated e.g. by parsing HTML) to a `ColumnText`

```
public class ColumnTextElementHandler : IElementHandler
{
    public ColumnTextElementHandler(ColumnText ct)
    {
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    ColumnText ct = null;

    public void Add(IWritable w)
    {
        if (w is WritableElement)
        {
            foreach (IElement e in ((WritableElement)w).Elements())
            {
                ct.AddElement(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, the test above produces a PDF with this content:

[image: page 1]

...

[image: page 2]

...

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I predominantly work with Java and have not used the `XmlWorker` before. Thus, this code may have considerable potential for improvement.</sub>

Comment: thanks for your detailed response. Another clarification, does iTextSharp HTML to PDF conversion supports at control level as well? Ex. Text box, buttons in HTML, will it get converted to PDF? In my case, after conversion, controls are not getting displayed in PDF

Comment: As mentioned in my disclaimer, I have not used the `XmlWorker` before. Thus, I'm not a good source on the extent of iText's HTML support and would suppose you had better make that an explicit new stackoverflow question. I know, though, from other questions flying by here, that its support is easily extendable, cf. the `CustomImageTagProcessor` in @Skary's answer. If some elements have not yet been implemented, you can simply add an appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to have understand you question right.

If you are asking how to parse HTML to PDF using iTextSharp here is the solutin i found time ago :

```
        using (Document document = new Document(size))
        {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            document.Open();
            document.NewPage();
            document.Add(new Chunk(""));

            var tagProcessors = (DefaultTagProcessorFactory)Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
            tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
            tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, new CustomImageTagProcessor());

            var charset = Encoding.UTF8;

            CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
            cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS());
            var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
            cssResolver.AddCss(srcCssData, "utf-8", true);

            var hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider()));
            hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors);
            var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer));
            var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
            var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
            var xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, charset);

            xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(srcFileData));

            document.Close();
        }
```

To get it work you need to add custom image processor to inline image in the HTML you provide to tha above converte function :

```
public class CustomImageTagProcessor : iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Image
{
    public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes = tag.Attributes;
        string src;
        if (!attributes.TryGetValue(HTML.Attribute.SRC, out src))
            return new List<IElement>(1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
            return new List<IElement>(1);

        if (src.StartsWith("data:image/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
            var base64Data = src.Substring(src.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            var imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagedata);

            var list = new List<IElement>();
            var htmlPipelineContext = GetHtmlPipelineContext(ctx);
            list.Add(GetCssAppliers().Apply(new Chunk((iTextSharp.text.Image)GetCssAppliers().Apply(image, tag, htmlPipelineContext), 0, 0, true), tag, htmlPipelineContext));
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Current EVO API accepts different parameters like header as a HTML string, body/content as a html string and footer as a HTML string. Finally, using the "PrepareRenderPdfPageEvent", it consolidates and build a complete PDF template.

Using iTextSharp, I have parsed the body HTML string to PDF using XMLParser. Is there any way to parse the header HTML string to PDF header the same way?

Comment: @Sam  can you provide to me an example of what you wuold add to PDF header from the HTML header?

Comment: @Skary Nice use of a custom tag processor. It might solve one or two yet unanswered questions on data URLs and iText(Sharp).

Comment: something like this is in a PDFPTable with a PDFPCell, (an already formatted HTML content)                                  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>1</title><style type="text/css">..three-col td {width: 33%;vertical-align: top;}.six-col td {width: 16%;}two-col td {width: 50%;}h2 {font-size: 16px;}ul {padding: 0 15px;}.center .. text-align:right;padding-right:45px;} </style></head><body><div class="page-header"><table style="margin: 25px 0px; border: 0; cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 0; width: 100%"...
</table>
</div></body></html>

Comment: so you wuold use CSS in the header.
First consider that iTextSharp has a poor css support, second try HtmlAgilityPack to parse your html header, and then load css as separated resources.

Css a separated resources or as inline resources are the only way i know to use css with iTextSharp.

Comment: Does iTextSharp HTML to PDF conversion supports at control level as well? Ex. Text box, buttons in HTML, will it get converted to PDF? In my case, after conversion, controls are not getting displayed in PDF